# Malformed expression in my last for loop and also null point exception need help to understand

Tags: java

```
while ((j <= k)&& j <listemiz.length) {
    if((listemiz[i].equals(instance[j].getIsim()))){

    }
    else{
       j++;
    }
    System.out.println("1");
}
```

**Class**

```
/**
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties. 
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates 
 * and open the template in the editor. 
 */
package c_veri_yapilari;

public class C_Veri_Yapilari {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic 
        int i;

        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Farklı Farklı Firmalarin isimleri A B C D E.. Harfleri ile Temsil
        // Edilecek
        String[] listemiz = new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "B", "B","C", "A"};
        // ArrayList<StructClass> arrayInstance = new ArrayList<StructClass>();
        // arrayInstance.add((String)listemiz[0]);

        StructClass[] instance = new StructClass[9];
        instance[0] = new StructClass();
        instance[0].isim = listemiz[0];
        instance[0].adress = 0;
        instance[0].sayisi = 1;
        int j;
        int k = 0;

        for (i = 1; i < listemiz.length; i++) {
            j = 0;
            System.out.println(listemiz[3]);
            while ((listemiz[i].equals(instance[j].getIsim())) && (j <= k)) {
                j++;
                System.out.println("1");
            }
            if (j > k) {
                System.out.println("2");
                k++;
                instance[k] = new StructClass();
                instance[k].isim = listemiz[i];
                instance[k].adress = i;
                instance[k].sayisi = 1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("3");
                instance[j].sayisi++;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            System.out.println(instance[i].getIsim());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the nullpointer
`StructClass[] instance = new StructClass[9];`
so in other words the length of the array is 9. however after that you are filling only the first element

```
instance[0] = new StructClass();
        instance[0].isim = listemiz[0];
        instance[0].adress = 0;
        instance[0].sayisi = 1;
```

So when you are iterating through the instance  array all tits elements except the first one are null, so when you are reaching the second element and calls

```
instance[j].getIsim()
```

you have the nullpointer.

About the Malformed expression, can you please provide more details

Comment: listemiz[i].equals doesn't throw the npc. it's instance that has the null-elements.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have copy/paste the wrong part of the expression. now the answer is edited. Thanks for noticing